# Pig Filter Syntax error, unexpected symbol

Tags: apache-pig

```
inputData = LOAD '$input' AS (line:chararray);
statusLineFilter = FILTER smallData BY (line MATHCES '^.* AppWrite-Dispatcher: Status code: [0-9]+$');
```

This code, when I run it, yields this error: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'line'

The log file says the exact same thing. I'm at a loss, because the exact same syntax is working in other scripts I've written.

Comment: You have misspelled `MATHCES`.

Comment: Of course it is. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid misspelling of key words I recommend you to use an IDE or a Text-Editor like emacs with the pig-mode.el which add syntax highlight ;)

Comment: You can use Sublime Text too ;)